# How to pass an array parameter with javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, json

I've to pass an `ids` array from a page to another page. I create `$ids` in PHP and I use use this with jQuery in this way:

```
var ids = <?php echo json_encode($ids); ?>;

jQuery(ids).each(function() {
    filters.push('ids[]=' + jQuery(this));
});
```

The URL result is the following:

```
http://url.it/?sort=newest&ids[]=[object%20Object]&ids[]=[object%20Object]&ids[]=[object%20Object]&ids[]=[object%20Object]&ids[]=[object%20Object]
```

I would like to have in the URL an array with all elements but I obtain all arrays with one element.

Can you help me?

Comment: `jQuery(ids)` will expect a valid selector string.  If ids should contains ids, then it would have to follow the pattern of `#id1, #id2, ...` at the point that you perform that action.  However it looks like ids will be json, and not this expected pattern.

Comment: It would help to not use jQuery. The native array functions are perfectly capable of doing what you want.

Comment: It's impossible to say without knowing what `$ids` contains (and, as a result, what `var ids` contains)

Answer (score -1):

```
var params = ids.map(id => 'ids[]=' + encodeURIComponent(id))
filters.concat(params)
```

Answer (score -1):

you do not need to do extra things. Just create your link like this:

```
var ids = <?= json_encode($ids); ?>;
var link = 'http://url.it/?sort=newest&ids=[' + ids.join(',') + ']';
```